# Can my web-app's welcome-file servlet take in POST data?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, http-post

I have a servlet used as the welcome-file of my web-app.
Is there a way I can make the doPOST method of the servlet called when this servlet gets called when I enter just the context-root?

web.xml:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/mainPage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>mainPage</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

MyServlet.Java:

```
  public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

      public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
          super.init(config);
      }

      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("GET");
      }

      public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("POST");
      }
 }
```

Say my context root is MyApp, is there a way, I can get POST printed by calling http://[host]:[port]/MyApp ?

Regards,
HeMan

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a form:

```
<form action='/mainPage' method='post'>
 <input type='text' name='param1' />
 <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

You can also make a POST request with AJAX or with a program written to use POST.  But you can't do it in any way in the browser address bar.

The basic difference between POST and GET is when you submit a form with GET the parameters show in the address bar and when you submit a form with POST they don't.  So it doesn't really make sense that anyone would want to invoke post simply from the address bar.